# Can I create a planar inductor using salt water?

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity, antennas

I know that in order to create an inductor for applications like NFC/antennas or electromagnets, I would need many concentric coils of a conductive material.
I was wondering if it’s possible to create an inductor that is planar with very small concentric circle offsets (~1mm or less) using salt water.

Comment: if you have current you also have magnetic field and salt water is a conductive electrolyte.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need many turns for an electromagnet or a loop antenna. What you need is a large circulating current. A common way to make a large circulating current is to drive a small current into many turns. But you could drive a large current into a single turn.

I don't understand how using salt water helps with this problem. Insulation would be a challenge, and it's not as conductive as metal, so you'd want conductors with a lot of cross section. However, if you can have a lot of water, it doesn't have to be particularly salty to have significant electromagnetic effects. I once turned an island in a lake into an effective [slot antenna](https://groups.google.com/g/rec.radio.shortwave/c/Ve6wLkFPnuE/m/ITMUjF82JIAJ).

Comment: Salt water is conductive, and it’s only speculating about the possibility of using different material for something that is historically made from conductive metal (copper etc, silver paste, gold)

Comment: @Kaito See edit.